# CameraAccessException Broken pipe while starting camera session

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am getting this CameraAccessException while attempting to create a capture session after the `onOpened()` Callback from `CameraDevice.StateCallback`

First the crashlog

```
Fatal Exception: android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): endConfigure:537: Camera 1: Error configuring streams: Broken pipe (-32)
       at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1127)
       at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.endConfigure(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:117)
       at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.configureStreamsChecked(CameraDeviceImpl.java:481)
       at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSessionInternal(CameraDeviceImpl.java:669)
       at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:517)
       at a.b.c.d.MainActivity.startCapturingSession(MainActivity.java:364)
       at a.b.c.d.MainActivity.access$startCapturingSession(MainActivity.java:36)
       at a.b.c.d.MainActivity$stateCallback$1.onOpened(MainActivity.java:90)
       at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:150)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

Caused by android.os.ServiceSpecificException: endConfigure:537: Camera 1: Error configuring streams: Broken pipe (-32)
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2102)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
       at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser$Stub$Proxy.endConfigure(ICameraDeviceUser.java:742)
       at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.endConfigure(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:114)
       at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.configureStreamsChecked(CameraDeviceImpl.java:481)
       at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSessionInternal(CameraDeviceImpl.java:669)
       at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:517)
       at a.b.c.d.MainActivity.startCapturingSession(MainActivity.java:364)
       at a.b.c.d.MainActivity.access$startCapturingSession(MainActivity.java:36)
       at a.b.c.d.MainActivity$stateCallback$1.onOpened(MainActivity.java:90)
       at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:150)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

The [Camera error doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraAccessException#CAMERA_ERROR) says the camera is in error state. Can this be due to anything being implemented wrongly from the app code?

My app code

```
private val stateCallback = object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice = camera
            startCapturingSession()
        }

        override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice = null
            camera.close()
        }

        override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
            onDisconnected(camera)
        }
    }

@WorkerThread
    private fun startCapturingSession() {

        val prevSurface = previewSurface ?: kotlin.run {
            throw IllegalStateException("Preview Surface is null while starting capture session")
        }

        reader1 = ImageReader.newInstance(
            PREVIEW_WIDTH, PREVIEW_HEIGHT,
            ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, IMAGE_READER_MAX_IMAGES
        )
        reader1!!.setOnImageAvailableListener(analyser, null)
        val surface1 = reader1!!.surface

        reader2 = ImageReader.newInstance(
            PREVIEW_WIDTH, PREVIEW_HEIGHT,
            ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, IMAGE_READER_MAX_IMAGES
        )
        reader2!!.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageAvailableListener, null)
        val surface2 = reader2!!.surface
        val device = cameraDevice
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("Camera Device null while capturing session")

        device.createCaptureSession( // this is line 364 from the crash log
            listOf(surface1, surface2, prevSurface),
            object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                }

                override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                    // more code here
                }
            }, null
        )
    }
```

At the worst case could I catch this and close and repoen the camera?

This does not occur always but successive trials of opening the app was failing.

Comment: IMHO: We already switched to CameraX, never the less it's in beta for now. If you are not writing a camera app it should be the best choice for you also.

Comment: Yes. AFAIK Camera2 is not deprecated, CameraX adds on top of it and provides a better api. I didnt choose it because it is still in beta and was hoping to get more support for Camera2 from the community in issues such as these

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and it was due to the aspect ratio of my preview. I implemented the following code to return me the correct preview size for my device. I found that the problem was the value i was passing to the aspect ratio(i was passing the size of the preview), and in some devices the camera crashed while trying to open. I was getting the CameraError(3) broken pipe exception.

```html
private static Size ChooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int textureViewWidth, int textureViewHeight,
            int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
        {
            var bigEnough = new List<Size>();
            var notBigEnough = new List<Size>();

            //Test different aspect ratios(4:3, 16:9)
            int w = 4;
            int h = 3;

            foreach(Size option in choices)
            {
                if(option.Width <= maxWidth && option.Height <= maxHeight)
                {
                    if(option.Height == option.Width * h                    / w)
                    {
                        if (option.Width >= textureViewWidth && option.Height >= textureViewHeight)
                        {
                            bigEnough.Add(option);
                        }
                        else
                            notBigEnough.Add(option);
                    }
                }
            }
           
            if (bigEnough.Count > 0)
                return (Size)Collections.Min(bigEnough, new ComparesSizeByArea());
            else if (notBigEnough.Count > 0)
                return (Size)Collections.Max(notBigEnough, new ComparesSizeByArea());
            else
            {   
                return choices[0];
            }
        }
```

The ComparesSizesByArea is a aux class with the following method:

```html
 public int Compare(Java.Lang.Object lhs, Java.Lang.Object rhs)
        {
            var lhsSize = (Size)lhs;
            var rhsSize = (Size)rhs;

            return Long.Signum((long)lhsSize.Width * lhsSize.Height - (long)rhsSize.Width * rhsSize.Height);
        }
```

On your extended textureView, constraint it to the width also:

```html
 protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.GetSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (ratioWidth == 0 || ratioHeight == 0)
            SetMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        else
        {
            if (width > (float)height * ratioWidth / ratioHeight)
                SetMeasuredDimension(width, width * ratioHeight / ratioWidth);
            else
                SetMeasuredDimension(height * ratioWidth / ratioHeight, height);
        }        
    }
```

Comment: With the code i have this appears to be an intermittent issue. If it is the aspect ratio this would lead to crash each time I try to open the camera I assume?

Comment: The resolutions your device can show are shown with StreamConfigurationMap on the CameraCharactheristics. I found that though your device is supporting several different aspect ratios from (4:3,16:9.....) if you set the aspect ratio to the minimum values it won't crash. With the code from above to fill the screen i had to after change the OnMeasure overriden method from my TextureView and constraint it according to the width

Comment: Any news regarding this issue @ArkaPravaBasu

Comment: Hi @M1tiens, this issue is kind of intermittent and I think happened when I was trying to resize my preview. But I do query for supported sizes in StreamConfigurationMap before choosing a size for my preview. Will update once I am able to find something interesting.

Comment: Hi @M1tiens, I was using [AutoFitSurfaceView](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/Camera2Basic/utils/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera/utils/AutoFitSurfaceView.kt) which takes care of the point you made. I was still getting this crash. I have described what I believe was going wrong in my answer. Thanks and appreciate your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was being caused by layout redraw which would cause the `SurfaceView` (for the camera preview) dimension to change. Upon change in dimension a new `Surface` would be created. The older one would be destroyed and the `CameraCaptureSession` associated with it could not be created.

I had to close the current camera capture session and create a new one upon change in my layout. Also had to add a debounce to prevent repeated updates within a short time period. Not the cleanest solution but looks to be working for now.